# Object from comprehension in CoffeeScript [dict/hash comprehensions]

Tags: coffeescript

is there a way to return an object from a comprehension in coffeescript?  something so that i could express this:

```
form_values = () ->
  ret = {}
  ret[f.name] = f.value for f in $('input, textarea, select')
  return ret
```

like this:

```
form_values = () -> f.name, f.value for f in $('input, textarea, select')
```

i'd like to construct a *single object* (not an array of objects).  so if the markup looks something like this:

```
<form name=blah>
  <input type=text name=blah1 value=111 />
  <textarea name=blah2>222</textarea>
  <select name=blah3>
    <option value=333a>
    <option value=333b>
  </select>
</form>
```

the returned object would be something like this:

```
{
  blah1: '111',
  blah2: '222',
  blah3: ''
}
```

Comment: There many implementations of `.serializeObject` for jQuery: https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/master/jquery.ba-serializeobject.js

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nope. Comprehensions only return arrays in CoffeeScript. Search the issue tracker for [object comprehensions](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/search?q=object+comprehensions), and you'll find several proposals, but none were found suitable.

Comment: a pity, object-comprehensions or, at least, some kind of functional object constructor should be part of the core.

Comment: I came back to this same post to find that I already voted this up.  I can't believe this is being ignored, it's super useful.

Answer (score 26):

```
form_values = new ->
  @[f.name] = f.value for f in $ 'input, textarea, select'
  this
```

or

```
form_values = new class then constructor: ->
  @[f.name] = f.value for f in $ 'input, textarea, select'
```

Comment: Late +1! This is very clever!

Comment: Clever, but completely unintelligible. Is there any way to make this more readable for the next generation?

Comment: It works as a one-liner too: `form_values = new -> @[f.name] = f.value for f in $('input, textarea, select'); this`

Comment: That's not a _one-liner_. You just put two statements on the same line using a semi-colon.

Comment: This does not produce the same results as OP's example did; their `form_values` is a function that returns an object whilst yours _is_ that object.

Answer (score 7):

Check the functional library [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) and the extension `_.mash` from this [mixin](https://gist.github.com/1222480):

```
form_values = ->
  _($('input, textarea, select')).mash f -> [f.name, f.value]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [underscore's object function](http://underscorejs.org/#object), you can do this:

```
form_values = _.object([f.name, f.value] for f in $('input, textarea, select'))
```

Comment: Either `_.object` is new or I've completely missed it all along.

Comment: If you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), then use the [`fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs#fromPairs) function instead.

Answer (score 4):

This has already been answered but probably lack of some explanations as this idiom is rather *cryptic* at first sight:

```
form_values = (new -> @[f.name] = f.value for f in $ 'input, textarea, select'; @)
//             ^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^  
//           create                      with                                   |
//           a new                       that                                   |
//           empty                     anonymous                                |
//           object                   constructor                               |
//                                                                don't forget -/
//                                                                to return the
//                                                             newly created object
```

The key idea is to create an empty object (`new`) with an anonymous constructor (`-> ...`) that will create the various fields.

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeScript's creator [suggests using a helper function](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/1360#issuecomment-1167087) to convert an array of pairs into an object:

```
form_values = toObject([f.name, f.value] for f in $('input, textarea, select'))
```

This is arguably the most readable way of doing it, within the current language syntax. It's also very similar to how Python and other languages do it, except for the missing syntactic sugar.

The helper function can be easily written once, using for example the technique from @matyr's and @Sylvain's answers:

```
// Create a new object from an array of [key, value] pairs.
toObject = (pairs) ->
    new -> @[key] = value for [key, value] in pairs; @
```

Comment: This function nets the same result as using lo-dash's `fromPairs`... `pairs = ([k,v*2] for k,v of {one: 1, two: 2 })` `object =  _.fromPairs pairs` -> `{ one: 2, two: 4 }`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with no added libraries right in CoffeeScript.

It should be something to the effect of:

```
$('input, textarea, select').each (item) => @form_values || @form_values = {}; @form_values[$(item).name] = $(item).value
```

You could simplify the syntax of that by pre-creating the form_values:

```
form_values = {}
$('input, textarea, select').each (item) -> form_values[$(item).name] = $(item).value
```

Here is a lengthier response with canned examples:

Take a very simple example where you wanted to map the obj to name value:

```
items = [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
items.map((item) -> {name: Object.keys(item)[0], value: item[Object.keys(item)[0]]})
```

> [ { name: 'a', value: 1 },
>     { name: 'b', value: 2 },
>     { name: 'c', value: 3 } ]

Note that the above is not really an Object comprehension, just demonstrating an example.

Now let's say there is a bit more structure and you just want to map a known unique key:

```
items = [{key: "abc", someVar: 1}, {key: "def", someVar: 2}]
```

In Python you'd do something simple like this: `{x['key']:x for x in items}`

In CoffeeScript you can get all of this down to one single line though with a caveat:

```
items.forEach (item) => @x || @x = {}; @x[item['key']] = item
```

> { abc: { key: 'abc', someVar: 1 },
>     def: { key: 'def', someVar: 2 } }

In the above code x was not previously defined in the scope, so using `=>` and `@` allowed us to bind `x` with the `@x || @x = {}` if not previously found, then set the key.

If you don't want to use => and @ you have to define x beforehand:

```
x = {}
items.forEach (item) => x || x = {}; x[item['key']] = item
```

> { abc: { key: 'abc', someVar: 1 },
>     def: { key: 'def', someVar: 2 } }

Answer (score 1):

Not to beat a dead horse, but I personally thing this is readable and satisfies the 'one line' requirement without needing extra modules:

```
form_values = {}; form_values[f.name] = f.value for f in $('input, textarea, select')
```

Don't forget you can still use a semi-colon to combine lines in Coffeescript!